# Displaying files from out of httpdocs location

Tags: php, file-upload, directory, special-folders, file-location

The files are going to be stored in a folder next to httpdocs. Thus, it will make hard to display those files to internet user. How I'll overcome this problem? I mean, I want to display/serve those files to the users. Probably I need to use some kind of proxy file?

Old one:

```
-httpdocs\
  -index.php
  -uploads\  <-
     -folder\
        -image.png
        -image3.jpg
     -folderbla\
        -personal.jpg
        -sp.pdf
```

New one:

```
-httpdocs\
   -index.php
-uploads\  <----
   -folder\
      -image.png
      -image3.jpg
   -folderbla\
      -personal.jpg
      -sp.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your web server to graft that directory into your URL space, e.g. using [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) with HTTPd.

Comment: Thanks. And, it seems that PHP does not obey to those rules. Is there any way to make PHP listen to Alias?

Comment: PHP doesn't care about your web server configuration beyond what PHP needs. If you want to use the URL space covered by an `Alias` directive in PHP then it is up to you to use it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP script and [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $file_name = $_GET['file'] or die();
    // sanitize, validate the string
    // check user permission
    file_get_contents($file_name);

?>
```